# Return json object as json-rpc response result

Tags: java, php, json-rpc

According to json-rpc spec 2.0, the response must contain result (on success), error (on failure) and id. So far all the examples I see online, for result they using primitive data type as integers or simple string. I am working on a project where I need to send some more data as a result of json-rpc call. So, I was thinking to send my result as json string and send it in the result value of the response object. For example:

```
$response = {"result": a_json_string, "error": null, "id": 1}
```

But on client side I am getting an error saying response is invalid json object. So should I stick with json-rpc specification and send only primitive value with json-rpc reponse object's result value or I can send a complex data as result value in the response but something is wrong in my coding, so that is why it's not working? If it is okay to send complext values in response, then I will debug my code to find the problem. But before that I just wanted to know if it's complying the standard or not.

My json-rpc server is written in php and client is written in java (a java application using the web services).

Answer (score 0):

`$response = {"result": a_json_string, "error": null, "id": 1}`

That isn't a JSON string, and it's not valid PHP, so you're not actually showing us your real code. (Curiously, but not relevantly, it's valid JavaScript code :-)

In any case, you don't need to JSON-ify the datastructure that was serialized to `a_json_string`.

For example, if you had a variable `$data` before and you were doing this:

```
$a_json_string = json_encode($data);
$response = json_encode(
                array("result" => $a_json_string, 
                      "error"  => null, 
                      "id"     => 1));
```

Instead, do this:

```
$response = json_encode(
                array("result" => $data, 
                      "error"  => null, 
                      "id"     => 1));
```

We'd need to see more of your code to understand specifically what other issues you might encounter with JSON serialization. For example, the JSON serializer *might* not be able (with certain data) to tell if you want an `Array` or `Object` JSON serialization of a PHP `array()` (i.e: you'll need to give it hints).

Comment: Sorry about the JSON string, I should've mentioned that it is pseudo code. I fixed the problem. In fact the solution is similar like your first part of code that you ask me not to do :) The problem was on the client side (java app).  I was expecting that the json-rpc client library I am using gives me the full json response object. But actually it inspects the response and depending on success/error, it gives either the result or the error message as string. So on success, the result string is actually a json string and I made json object from it and everything works fine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If an approach like the 1st "fixed" it for you, you're doing JSON-RPC wrong. You shouldn't try to just "print" the `result` field of the JSON-RPC envelope. It's a JSON "value", which could be a `String`, `Number`, `Object`, `Array` or the value `null`. Instead, you should determine what data-structure has been transmitted (or agree on a convention beforehand) such that you know what you've received and how it can be "printed".

Comment: I think I quite didn't understand your comment, especially the "try to just print" part. What I find out that I am able to send complex values (as json object) as the result value of json-rpc response. And both json-rpc client and server under my control, so I know/control the exact set of methods and their params and param types. The json-rpc server written in php and the client is an adroid app written in java.

Comment: Excellent. As you're in control of the implementation of both client and server, you don't need to 'double-encode' the `result` field of the JSON-RPC envelope (as per the 1st example) on the server end. Simply arrange for the client end to appropriately access the contents of the `result` field.